# iphone custom navigationBar singleton or not?

Tags: iphone, singleton, uinavigationbar

I am using my own custom navigationBar, but i need to access it in a number of different views because i need to add buttons, change title and so forth.

Should i pass a reference to my navigationBar each time i show a new view, or just make it a singleton so i can access it from any view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make it a global variable.

Comment: i am reading things on the web that say its not best practice to use global vars, instead use singletons

Comment: I would avoid using a global variable if at all possible, as it eschews encapsulation. Say you need to do a modal view controller, which is going to have to have a similar navigation bar. Oops, now both navigation controllers are going to be trying to use the same navigation bar, which won't end up good.

Comment: Let me make myself clearer: use a global variable as long as using a global variable is simpler than the alternatives.

Answer (score 3):

Neither.

You've listed adding buttons and changing titles as the reasons you need a custom toolbar, but both of those things can be done through the navigation controller with no need to create your own and therefore no need to create a singleton or a global variable.

When you push a new view controller, you can set the title for the navigation bar simply by calling [self setTitle:@"Nav Title"]; in the -viewDidLoad of that view controller. If you need to add a button, use code like the following (also in -viewDidLoad):

```
[[self navigationItem] setRightBarButtonItem:[[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
        initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemEdit 
                             target:self 
                             action:@selector(setEditing)] autorelease]];
```

In other words, your design is flawed if you are creating a custom navigation bar only for the reasons you've listed. I suppose there are some good reasons to create a custom navigation bar, but these are not among them.

Consider reviewing the [Configuring the Navigation Item Object](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/NavigationControllers/NavigationControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH103-SW37) section of the [View Controller Programming Guide for iPhone OS](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/NavigationControllers/NavigationControllers.html).

Best regards,

Answer (score 2):

Are you using a UINavigationController?  If so, you can access the navigation bar from any sub-controller like this:

```
UINavigationBar *bar = self.navigationController.navigationBar;
```